# Frank (Cucumber) - Detecting first run

Tags: ios, cucumber, frank, acceptance

I want to write a test that says if this is the first time the app is being launched, then directions should be displayed. How can i detect the first app launch with Frank? I was thinking use NSUserDefaults, but I still don't know how to do that. Example step definition code would be great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the fact that an `NSUserDefaults` not previously set is nil:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *firstRun = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"firstRun"];
if (firstRun == nil)
{
    [userDefaults setValue:@YES forKey:@"firstRun"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    // Do what you want here
}
```

Comment: Right but frank step definitions are in ruby. My question is: How do you check this from within a frank step definition?